# How do I fix this discoloration in my model?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, object-mode

How can I fix this model discoloration?
Hello,

I was wondering what is causing the discoloration on this model?  It should be a smooth surface.

[image: In Object Mode]

Here's another screenshot in edit mode:
[image: In Edit Mode]

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you have overlapping faces resulting in Z-Fighting. Try to remove doubles in edit mode. You should consider quad based modeling.

Comment: can you add a blend file to your question?  It appears that Dontwalk is correct. In edit mode, select all vertices and then use the 'remove doubles' command to see if that solves the problem.  Alternatively, but less likely, you may have non manifold geometry, such as when one face intersects another. You can check this quickly in edit mode by using the select menu, select all by trait, no manifold option.

Comment: also just to be sure press Ctrl+N to recalculate the normals of the model

Comment: Thanks for the info. i'll try it right away, thank you.  oh a question that just popped up when reading the comments.  Is z-fighting the same thing as a rats nest?

Comment: Dontwalk, unfortunately I inherited the object, didn't make it.  Not that I could do better.  Is there a way to convert triangles to quads once something has been built?  So, I removed all the doubles and there were a ton, but that didn't fix the problem.  So I started carefully removing faces and that worked out.  I don't know why but it appears there were layers of faces stacked on each other.

Comment: I tried to use Ctrl-N to recalculate the normals as suggested, but Ctrl-N only brought up a dialog asking if i want to reload the start up files.  I must be on a different version of blender

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple faces partially overlapping each other.  By removing the extra layers, the model returned to a smooth looking surface.

Thanks all for the assistance.